# How to get files starting specific name on WinSCP?

Tags: winscp

How to get files starting specific name?
I have script like this

```
open Area_4@10.54.18.18 

get -neweronly "/Payload/Daily/2017/Daily_Payload_BH_2*.csv" "D:\FTP-NSQM\2_Payload"
get -neweronly "/Payload/Daily/2017/Daily_Payload_BH_3*.csv" "D:\FTP-NSQM\3_Payload"
```

I used batch file for execute this script, but nothing happened

If i don't use a specific name (Daily_Payload_BH_2*.csv or Daily_Payload_BH_3*.csv) for get a new files

```
get -neweronly "/Payload/Daily/2017" "D:\FTP-NSQM\2_Payload"
```

This script executed properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is ambiguous.

To get comparable results use:

```
get -neweronly "/Payload/Daily/2017/Daily_Payload_BH_2*.csv" "D:\FTP-NSQM\2_Payload\"
get -neweronly "/Payload/Daily/2017/Daily_Payload_BH_3*.csv" "D:\FTP-NSQM\3_Payload\"
```

and

```
get -neweronly "/Payload/Daily/2017/*" "D:\FTP-NSQM\2_Payload\"
```

These should get you consistent results.

Note the `/*` in source paths and the trailing backslash in target paths.

Excerpts from [`get` command documentation](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_get) (emphasis mine):

> Filename can be replaced with [wildcard](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask) to select multiple files. **To download all files in a directory, use mask `*`**.
>
> The last parameter specifies target local directory and optionally [operation mask](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/operation_mask) to store file(s) under different name. Destination directory **must end with backslash**.

---

*If this does not help, we need to see complete log files of both scripts.*

Comment: Thanks @Martin Prikryl
It solved my problem, add backslash on directory target :)